# How to set not to fetch git lfs files by git attributes?

Tags: git, git-lfs

In a C++ project, I store some test data with git lfs, in the same repository as the source code. I do not always want to build the tests, and in this case, I do not want to download the large files, either.

I know that it is possible to skip the lfs fetch by passing some arguments to git clone. But this depends on the user, and I want to enforce this in the repository.

The idea is that the test data was *never* fetched when the project is cloned. It would be downloaded later when the project is *configured*, depending on whether building the tests is opted in.

Is that possible at all?

Maybe with filter attributes?